# Unable to load DLL 'System.Data.SQLite.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) for some customers

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll

Some of my customers are getting this error:

```
Unable to load DLL 'System.Data.SQLite.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) for some customers
```

So far, I think about 20% of my customers can't open the software because of this. Here are the ways I've tried to fix it:

1. Put SQLite file in .exe folder
2. Put SQLite file in system32 folder
3. Merge SQLite file with .exe (SmartAssembly)

I really need a fix for it, because atleast 1 in 5 customers can't use my software now.
Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who find this and have no idea how to fix it, the issue was in the C++ framework that was installed. The SQLite DLL could be found but it couldn't be loaded. Stupidly enough it wasn't showing me that error, it was showing me this one.

Comment: how did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Set 'Copy to output folder' in reference properties and recompile your software - it will fix your problem.

Comment: I'm using WPF, and I can't seem to find that option. Copy Local is set to True though.